# SQL update row once a month

Tags: php, sql

I'm creating voting system in my web app. Want to reset votes every month with cron. But I came across a problem I don't know how to select a row each month by date added. So if today is 8. August i need to select all rows from 8. day in every month.

I apologize for this stupid question, I'm still learning.

Comment: You need to store that information in each row.  Also, if you are going by day of the month, what happens to starts on Jan 31?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Do you mean the date the row was added? I store the date and time when the row was created

Comment: What i need is set number of votes to 0 once a month from date when row created. Its about days not months. For months with 31 days it can be selected first day of next month

Comment: Sample data and desired results would clarify what you want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- store the current month in the database
- use date('m') to check IF the current month is > than the stored one.
- if TRUE, run your "voting reset" code AND increase the stored month by one.

this code should execute whenever someone opened that page.